# Aligning of "=" sign in three-row formulas

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

How to align a "=" in the last formula that it was under the last sign "=" of the second formula.

Here is my attempts

```
\begin{align}
E=\dot{\theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}-L &= \nonumber \\
&=\frac{m}{2}(R^2\dot\theta^2+R^2\omega^2\sin^2\theta)+mgR\cos\theta  &=  \nonumber \\
& &=  T+U 
\end{align}
```

Comment: You need ampersands in the first line, too.

Comment: Why do you have `=` at the end of first two lines?

Comment: @ Harish Kumar Because traditional characteristics of typesetting for cyrilics

Comment: @ Matthew Leingang yes, but problem is still remain

Answer (score 4):

(1) Always post full minimal examples, better chance of help if people get something to work on where they do not have to add anything i order to compile it

(2) Align is not the best solution in this case, use `alignat`. Also remember the number of `&`'s per line will be 2x numbers of alignments - 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
E&=\dot{\theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}-L &&= \nonumber \\
&=\frac{m}{2}(R^2\dot\theta^2+R^2\omega^2\sin^2\theta)+mgR\cos\theta  &&=  \nonumber \\
&& &=  T+U 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

(Answer updated to incorporate the comments of daleif and barbarabeeton.)

I should think that (i) aligning the rows on the first `=` symbols and (ii) adding `=` symbols at the end rows 1 and 2 accomplishes what you need. I'm following the usage suggested on p. 184 of the book "LaTeX po-russki" by Igor Kotelnikov and Platon Chebotaev.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E &=\dot{\theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}-L = \nonumber \\
  &=\frac{m}{2}(R^2\dot\theta^2+R^2\omega^2\sin^2\theta) +mgR\cos\theta = \nonumber \\
  &= T+U
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is old tradition in eastern Europe to duplicate the `=`. I think even western europeans used to do this as well into the 1920's (or something like that)

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for explaining this issue. I wasn't familiar with it.

Comment: I only know because some *old* people at my work told me about it.

Comment: some information on russian typesetting traditions can be found in tugboat: [m.i. grinchuk](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-4/tb53grin.pdf); there's one nice example on p.184 of a book ["latex2e po-russki"](http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/kotelnikovchebotaev2004b.pdf) by i.kotel'nikov and p.chebotaev, several examples on p.9 of ["math formulas in latex2e"](http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/Math_in_LaTeX.pdf) by V Syumkin, and probably other examples in links on the page http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc.html -- this is a nice up-to-date russian-language list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and daleif - Many thanks for these comments! I've updated my answer accordingly.